# Textures black out after remesh?

Tags: texturing, uv, photogrammetry

I have photoscanned a fire hydrant and as all photoscanned objects are, its mesh is a total wreck. So I remeshed it using Quadriflow remesh. But after the remesh was complete, the new object was completely black (left object). I can't just unwrap the object because the textures are baked onto the image for the photoscan and are totally random (as seen on the right.) How do I apply the textures to my new object just like my old object?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Quadriflow remesh will remove any UVs you have, one solution is to use [*Data Transfer*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/data_transfer.html) modifier on the remeshed version, to transfer UVs from the photoscan to the remeshed version, use settings in the image below, you should also place both meshes in the same location, and preferably hide the photoscan

Another solution is to use the [*Remesh Modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/retopology.html) instead of quadriflow at the cost of low topology quality.

[image: Data transfer modifier blender]

Comment: Thanks! It worked mostly but all the textures were split apart at the seams. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Not sure about this one, maybe we could experiment on the blend file